# Python :.2f strange behavior

Tags: python, format, f-string

I had experimented with some code on Python and I got strange results with :.2f.

```py
>>> a = 4.34567
>>> a
4.34567
>>> f"{a:.2f}"
'4.35'
>>> "%.2f" % a
'4.35'
>>> "{:.2f}".format(a)
'4.35'
>
```

I expected results like:

```py
>>> a = 4.34567
>>> a
4.34567
>>> f"{a:.2f}"
'4.34'
>>> "%.2f" % a
'4.34'
>>> "{:.2f}".format(a)
'4.34'
>
```

Also I getting strange results with other number (:.3f, ...)
But I haven't seen strange results with :.5f

```py
>>> f"{a:.3f}"
'4.346'
>>> f"{a:.f}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
>>> f"{a:.4f}"
'4.3457'
>>> f"{a:.5f}"
'4.34567'
```

I seen this in Python 3.11.2 on Linux. I didn't tried to reproduce it on old python version.
Is that bug or feature?

Comment: This is a feature! F-String always rounds the floats to their decimal places: Thats why 3.34567 = 3.45

Comment: To get the float without rounding, you can use `str(a)[:n]`,  with `n` being the number of decimal places + 2. For arbitrary `a`, it's a little less elegant with `str(a)[:math.log(a)+n]`.

Comment: Thanks! I already thought that I found bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, but a feature. :.2f always rounds output. To print float without rounding You need to use str(a)[:n], where a is float and n is count of digits

Comment: _"n is count of digits"_ - That's going to be off by one. You need to slice an additional index to include the decimal point.